# Belgian Fruit Beer Expectations

Tags: beer, lambics

I am about to try a [Kreik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriek) beer.  This is a step beyond a Lamic, and I am having trouble locating actual sour Morello cherries.  Will any variety of a sour cherry get roughly equivalent results?

Comment: Belgian Lambic Kriek beers actually (traditionally) use a variety of cherry that is only grown in Belgium (and is becoming scarce). I forget the variety name now but they talk about it in the book Wild Brews, I do know it's not Morello.

Comment: Montmorency is another good variety of sour cherries, and they're fairly common in the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, any variety of sour cherry will give you equivalent results.

Answer (score 2):

Oregon fruit company cans unsweetened sour cherries that I've used to make a flavored cider before. Check the wine section of your local homebrew supply.